# Angular 2 Form Required validation fires after submit

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I have created a form that creates a sort of social media Post. The problem is that after all the fields are filled out, and I hit submit, the validation still fires after the post is submitted. I have been looking through the angular 2 docs and there doesn't seem to be any talk about this happening. I cant accept a hack for this fix. Is there something wrong with my form? or did I miss something in the docs when discussing the `required` call. Below is my plunker with the issue, thank you for any help in advance.

[plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/awOCs5y14TQZCny5mUrn?p=preview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
addPost(post){
        if(this.newPost != null && 
            post &&
            this.newPost.title.length>=1 &&
            this.newPost.description.length>=1){
                this.posts.unshift(this.newPost);
                this.newPost = new Post();
                return false // add this line
        }
    }
```

Edit: adding `return false` at the end in `if` block.